# How to implement the animation like 'Haze' did

Tags: ios, animation, ios6, opengl-es-2.0, quartz-graphics

First of all, I want to say this is not ads for Haze, it is trying to copy it, it is questions when I try to figure out how to implement the animation technology of [haze](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/haze/id594476963?mt=8).

Maybe there are two choices : OpenGL and QuartZ, the later makes use of CPU and maybe has the performance issue.

Question here is to look for more clues so that I can have further understanding of such cool animation.

Comment: So let's say someone wants to help you, they should buy the app, see the animation and then tell you their idea?

Comment: I assume that Haze is famous for its creative design so that I need think about it. Not necessary to buy, some video or news can help. http://www.engadget.com/2013/02/15/haze-for-ios/

Comment: This is some good animation. I'll try to do something that distantly looks like this, but I'm sure it all comes down to good planed  animations and good images to animate. Use blocks and change ImageView frames and alpha, thats what I will try.

Comment: Don't you think such animation effect could be draw via opengl rendering ? Good to see that you are interested in this also.Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is OpenGL at work. The way the smaller orbiting circles sort of morph out of the central one is not something you'd easily accomplish using UIKit or Quartz. Perhaps Core Animation, which is a bit of a bridge between OpenGL and Quarts/UIKit but more than likely they just coded it from scratch in OpenGL.

But not necessarily.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Do you know some UIKit or Quartz sample to achieve such cool animation ?

Comment: Apple's sample apps include some impressive uses of Quartz to do motion graphics. I haven't looked at most of them in a while, but if you pour through the online documentation you will come up with many. Here is a pretty good list of Apple's online code samples and projects: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code